# Ensuring at least one item in an array exists in another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I have the following models:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :countries
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_many :entitlements
    has_many :countries, :through => :entitlements
end
```

Posts on the Post index page must have at least one country that is the same as one of the Users' countries.

I have tried various scopes in my models and lengthy controller code but I can't figure out how to check what should be a simple relationship: whether at least one item in Post.countries exists in User.countries.

Any help greatly received.

**UPDATED:**

Ok, so I've got the following in my controller:

```
  def index
    @user = current_user
    @user.countries.each do |user_country|  
       @user_country_posts += Country.find(user_country.id).posts
    end
    @posts = @user_country_posts
  end
```

Which is iterating through the user.countries and finding each post for those countries. But when I run it I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: i dont get it.. show only posts, which have 1 country at least?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use the `@user_country_posts` instance variable which was not defined before, so its value is `nil`.

At the line:

```
@user_country_posts += Country.find(user_country.id).posts
```

You're actually calling the `+` method on the `@user_country_posts` variable, which is equivalent therefore with calling `+` on a `nil`.

Try to initialize the variable in the beginning of the method, like:

```
@user_country_posts = []
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also consider using ruby's union approach:
ie:

```
[1,2,4] & [1,4,5]
=> [1,4]
```

So if you have list of user countries and a list of post countries then maybe the below would work:
ie:

```
@shared_country_ids = @user.countries.map(&:id) & @post.countries(&:id)
```

From your update above what it seems like you want to do is show all posts that have one of the user's country codes. If that's the case I would do the below:
ie:

```
@posts = Post.where(:countries => @user.countries)
```

The above should work assuming you configured the relationships correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work as the relationship between Post and Countries is done through a join table (countries_posts) generated because of the HABTM relationship. Additionally, wouldn't your last command on show posts where *all* countries match the user's countries?